# NativeScript/Angular - Cannot find primary outlet to load component

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've got a problem with using `children` routes in one of my lazy loaded routes in a nativescript app. When I try to access either of signin or signup I just get an error saying `Cannot find primary outlet to load 'SigninComponent'`, which doesn't make sense to me.

This is my router module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: CompanyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'signin',
        loadChildren: 'routes/+company/routes/+signin/signin.module#SigninModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})

export class CompanyRouterModule {}
```

This is the lazy loaded module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule, 
    CompanyRouterModule
  ],
  exports: [CompanyRouterModule],
  declarations: [CompanyComponent]
})

export class CompanyModule {}
```

And finally the template of the `CompanyComponent` has an outlet:

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

Why isn't this working?

**EDIT**

This is the top route configuration, so the `signin` route is accessed via `/company/signin`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './routes/+home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'company',
    loadChildren: './routes/+company/company.module#CompanyModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [
    NativeScriptRouterModule
  ]
})

export class AppRouterModule {}
```

Comment: Can you share module configuration for `SignupModule`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad No, it's identical to signin just with different a different name. Removed it from the config since it's irrelevant to the question :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Where is the route that references `SigninComponent` defined?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Added top route configuration.

Comment: So you are trying to lazy load `company` and in turn lazy load `signup`? I don't know that that is a supported scenario.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It is when not using nativescript, so I'd assume that it should also work in the same way when using it. But I don't know, you could be right.

Comment: Actually it should work then. I was under the impression that this was not supported for web apps either. That may have been fixed but there was a long discussion on GitHub about it not being supported.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Interesting, I've been using it for a good 6 months at least.